# How to use Voltage Supervisor and MOSFET to switch off ESP32 supply?

Tags: solar-cell, esp32, low-battery

I am planning a solar project using following components:

- Solar cells
- 18650 battery
- TP4056
- MCP1700-3302E
- [TC54VN2902EZB Voltage Supervisor](http://www.microchip.com/mymicrochip/filehandler.aspx?ddocname=en011681)
- [IRLZ44N](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irlz44n.pdf)
- and an ESP32

I have only seen a block diagram for using the voltage supervisor and the IRLZ44N.  I want to protect the 18650 from discharge below the threshold of the voltage supervisor.

Any changes to ensure safe charging of 18650 battery?

[image: schematic]

Comment: By following the datasheets of the applicable devices. Provide the datasheets to us, and we may be able to point out where you need to look. Without them it would be guessing on our part.

Comment: This kind of thing is extremely tricky to get right, and likely cannot be done with your chosen parts unless you are willing to keep the supervisor itself powered.  The reason is that the protection diodes and keeper resistor will end up re-powering the circuit enough to re-activate the switch after it tries to switch itself off.  Making it work requires one FET *not* equipped with an ESD diode, inverting the signal feeding the power FET.

Comment: connect TC54VN2902EZB Voltage Supervisor to "+out" not to "B+"

Comment: Deepak thank you.  Corrected cicuit diagram..

Comment: If you're going to keep the regulator and supervisor themselves connected to the battery anyway, why don't you just pick a regulator with an enable input?

Comment: Schmatic of finished circuit:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rDX225zFbJ3IsmkuUIiRVS1cLlBC7m8T/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You should carefully calculate the value of resistor R2 and the capacitor C1 value. I would like you to follow my below-attached reference schematic for the TC54 with IRLZ44N.

https://www.flux.ai/ramprakashvishnoi8/tc54-voltage-supervisor-with-irlz44n-rectifier

Let me hear any questions from your side.

Comment: Welcome :-) (a) Please click "edit" below your answer and add an image of the schematic into the question too. Link-only answers, which point to an answer elsewhere, are considered "not an answer" here - see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). (b) Please don't add your signature into the answer - it breaks [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) site rule. I have removed it for you this time. (c) Please read the [tour] and [help] to see more about the site rules and philosophy. Thanks.

Comment: FYI, although this page relates to promotion, as it says [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/promotion): "*Links are not a substitute for including information in your answer itself [...]*". Also, since the page you linked is clearly your design, I slightly modified the text in your answer to make that clearer to readers.